# Android Bundle doesn't recognize serializable object as serialized

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, serializable

I'm trying to pass a serializable object in a bundle.

When trying to retrieve the object in another Activity, I get the error:

> "Incompatible Types:
>
> Required:  com.xxxxxx.Warmup (My serializable object - xxx padding
>   for package name)
>
> Found:  java.io.Serializable"

Code where the object is put in the bundle:

```
// Display the Exercise Category List by
            // starting the ExerciseCategoryMainActivity
            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(getContext(), ExerciseCategoryMainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Warmup.class.getSimpleName(), warmup);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Code where I try to retrieve the object (and get error message incompatible types):

```
// Get the attached bundle from the intent
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    Warmup warmup = extras.getSerializable(Warmup.class.getSimpleName());
```

And the code showing that my object is Serializable:

```
public class Warmup implements Serializable {
public static final long serialVersionUID = 20180228L;
```

Comment: Figured this one out myself, and the solution was pretty simple.  Just needed to cast the extras as a Warmup:

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer, and it was pretty simple.

All I needed to do was to cast the extra as a Warmup:

Warmup warmup = (Warmup) extras.getSerializable(Warmup.class.getSimpleName());